# An infinite sum in the product of sines

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, contest-math, taylor-expansion

This is an undergrad or lower level question I need help with.

Evaluate  $$\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin{\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{2a}{3^n}\right)}$$

where a is just some real constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline

Use $\sin a\sin b = \frac{1}{2}( \cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b))$.
Expand the summation, it will be a telescoping series. All terms except 2 will cancel out. As n becomes large, one of the terms will tend to 1, the other one will be $\cos a$. The final answer should be $1 - \cos a$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Notice $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2a}{3^n}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2a}{3^n}\right)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{a}{3^n}-\frac{2a}{3^n}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{a}{3^n}+\frac{2a}{3^n}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{a}{3^{n-1}}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using Werner's fomrula:

$$2\sin\dfrac a{3^n}\cdot\sin\dfrac{2a}{3^n}=\cos\dfrac{2a-a}{3^n}-\cos\dfrac{2a+a}{3^n}=f(n)-f(n-1)$$

where $f(m)=\cos\dfrac a{3^m}$

which leads to Telescoping Series